# Pasar datos como objetos desde mysql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, api

Estoy desarrollando una api con NodeJS y MySQL. Lo quiero lograr es que al listar los usuarios y relacionando las tablas, estas se puedan ver como objetos. Es decir, la tabla perfil o la tabla historial, sean un objeto dentro de los datos del usuario.

Trate de buscar esta duda, pero no logro resolver o algo debo estar pasando por alto.

Dejo especificado como estoy trabajando. Debajo están los resultados; el actual y el que trato de obtener.

Tabla usuarios

```
id | nombre | email
----------------------------
 1 | pepe   | pepe@mail.com
 2 | luis   | luis@mail.com
 3 | ana    | ana@mail.com
```

Tabla perfil

```
id_perfil | id_user | direccion | fecha_nac
--------------------------------------------
 1        | 1       | calle 1   | 2000-02-12
 2        | 2       | calle 2   | 1990-06-26
 3        | 3       | calle 3   | 2003-11-03
```

Script

```
const getUsers = async(req, res) => {
  try{
    const connection = await getConnection();
    const result = await connection.query(`SELECT 
        u.*, 
        p.direccion, 
        p.fecha_nac 
        FROM 
        usuario u 
        INNER JOIN 
        perfil p 
        WHERE u.id = p.id_user
    `);
    // console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
  } catch(error){
    res.status(500);
    res.send(error.message);
  }
};
```

Resultado actual

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "pepe",
    "email": "pepe@gmail.com",
    "direccion": "calle 1",
    "fecha_nac": "2000-02-12"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "luis",
    "email": "luis@gmail.com",
    "direccion": "calle 2",
    "fecha_nac": "1990-06-26",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "ana",
    "email": "ana@gmail.com",
    "direccion": "calle 3",
    "fecha_nac": "2003-11-03"
  }
]
```

Resultado a obtener

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "pepe",
    "email": "pepe@gmail.com",
    "perfil": [
       {
        "id_perfil": 1,
        "direccion": "calle 1",
        "fecha_nac": "2000-02-12"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

Desde ya agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de MySQL usas?

Comment: Cito desde phpMyAdmin: `Versión del cliente de base de datos: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.1.6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este es el clásico dilema de usar bases de datos relacionales vs bases de datos orientadas a documentos.

A menos que la herramienta con la que haces tus consultas ya provea una forma de hacer esto por ti (te recomiendo mirar la documentación de ese módulo sql de node que estas usando), primero tendrás que sacar los usuarios y luego buscar la dirección por cada usuario para ir formando la estructura JSON que deseas:

```
const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const connection = await getConnection();
    // obtenemos solo los usuarios:
    const users = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuario');
    const result = [];

    // por cada usuario, consultamos su(s) perfil(es):
    for (const user of users) {
      const profiles = await connection.query(
        `SELECT * FROM perfil p WHERE p.id_user = ${user.id}`,
      );

      // construyes la estructura que deseas,
      // en este caso simplemente se agregan los perfiles:
      result.push({
        ...user,
        perfil: profiles,
      });
    }

    res.json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500);
    res.send(error.message);
  }
};
```

Alternativamente lo que podrías hacer sería reusar la respuesta inicial del join y transformar el objeto a tu gusto:

```
const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const connection = await getConnection();
    // consultas la información en conjunto:
    const queryResult = await connection.query(`SELECT 
        u.*,
        p.direccion, 
        p.fecha_nac 
        FROM
        usuario u
        INNER JOIN 
        perfil p
        WHERE u.id = p.id_user
    `);
    // procedes a procesar el resultado:

    // define un "diccionario" auxiliar para evitar mucho procesamiento serial
    // es decir, una especie de "cache" para los usuarios:
    const aux = {};

    // reduce el resultado a la lista de usuarios con su(s)
    // respectivo(s) perfil(es):
    const result = queryResult.reduce((res, info) => {
      if (!aux[info.id]) {
        // si el usuario no esta en la cache, agreguelo:
        aux[info.id] = {
          id: info.id,
          name: info.name,
          email: info.email,
          perfil: [],
        };
      }

      // si el usuario ya esta en cache, simplemente procedes a
      // agregarle el/los perfil(es) asociados:
      aux[info.id].perfil.push({
        direccion: info.direccion,
        fecha_nac: info.fecha_nac,
      });

      // por último agregas el objeto construido al array resultante
      res.push(aux[info.id]);

      return res;
    }, []);

    res.json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500);
    res.send(error.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauro. Voy a tomar tu ejemplo para mejor la api.